# Changing Edubuntu to Ubuntu Studio

Tags: command-line, system-installation

I have installed Edubuntu 14.04 in my laptop. I wrongly installed this flavor without any idea about the various flours of Ubuntu versions. How can install or degrade it to Normal/Default Ubuntu Studio ?
(I need a method other than uninstalling this one and reinstalling Ubuntu Studio)

Comment: Do you want Ubuntu Studio (which is designed for multimedia content authoring) or regular/default Ubuntu?

Comment: I wan the Regula/Default Ubuntu

Comment: The easiest way might be to just start over and install Ubuntu, similarly to how you installed Edubuntu. But if you don't want to do that,  you could follow @Frantique 's answer, but replace `ubuntustudio-desktop` with `ubuntu-desktop`.

Comment: ya thanks.  My friend done that step (Reinstalling Ubuntu) to  get Ubuntu. And it's  done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this command?

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get remove --purge edubuntu-desktop && sudo apt-get install ubuntustudio-desktop
```

Comment: What it will do ?

Comment: It will remove edubuntu and will switch to Ubuntu Studio without reinstall.

Comment: Is it completely remove all themes and softwares installed with Edubuntu ?

Comment: Everything installed by the metapackage, yes.

Comment: To remove all the now unnecessary dependencies of the `edubuntu-desktop` meta-package, you need to run `apt-get auto-remove` or, better yet, add the `--auto-remove` flag to `apt-get install`.